# Choosing capture devices in Win32 app

Tags: c++, winapi, webrtc, directshow, chromium-embedded

I have an Win32 application based on Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF3) API. In embedded browser window displays the web-page, that uses WebRTC-connection to communicate with another side that has the same application. So we have real-time videochat between two sides.

Now I should provide users an ability to choose capture devices (microphone and webcam) for WebRTC session if the system has several ones, because browser window captures only default devices. The problem is that CEF3 API doesn't provide that functionality (documentation nothing says about it, also there are no answers on official CEF forum in [topic about this question](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12991&sid=8604afb99cc53585cf98d162a115dd08)).

Is there any way to implement that task via Win32 API? I found some information about how to enumerate devices (using SetupDi* functions, using DirectShow API), but not about how to enable/disable a specific device for my app. What exactly I should use for solve this problem?

Advice please, I'll be thankful for any help. It will be nice to see the code examples, if possible.

Comment: The official way to select the device is using javascript, see http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12876&p=25871&hilit=javascript+webrtc#p25512 There was previously a bug that prevented this, it has been fixed, I'm references as it provides some background information see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1335/webrtc-and-camera-selection

Comment: @amaitland Thank you very much!
Now I understand the vector I should follow by

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at microsoft samples of directshow. It's all over there. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Provide context for links: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link**, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*

Comment: @Rafael I saw this link, before asked my question yet, thank you